# ipa characters in \dfrac or in line table?

Tags: tables, fractions, tipa

I need to display an alignment of two words within a line of text, with one word above the other (see attached image), but I don't know how i could do it in Latex.
The problem is that the words contain special, IPA characters.

I tried to use \dfrac combined with the \tipa package, but it does not work because the math environment does not parse the tipa elements.

I was thinking perhaps to use a small two rows table, but then how do I put them within the line of text?

Edit:

here what i tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

bla bla bla \textipa{$\frac{(T - i - G - a - t - E - r - a)}{(d - O: - 0 - 0 - t - @ - 0 - 0)}$} or $\frac{(\textipa{T} - i - \textipa{G} - a - t - \textipa{E} - r - a)}{(d - \textipa{O}: - 0 - 0 - t - \textipa{@} - 0 - 0)}$ bla bla bla


\end{document}
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

---

[image]

Comment: Make a minimal example so what we can test if solutions works with ipa.

Comment: sorry, just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

bla bla bla 
$\frac{\text{(\textipa{T - i - G - a - t - E - r - a})}}
      {\text{(\textipa{d - o - 0 - x - t - @ - R - 0})}}$ 
or {\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{cc}\textipa{T - i - G - a - t - E - r - a}\\\hline
                      \textipa{d - o - 0 - x - t - @ - R - 0} 
    \end{tabular}}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah perfect, I didn't know you can use the \text within the math environment! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a fraction, is it? I guess you only to `\frac` because that gives you the two entries stacked together separated by a horizontal line. You can also do that with a tabular:

```
\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\hline#2\end{tabular}}
```

and then use `\pfrac` (pseudo frac) instead of `\frac`.